# Image recognition library/API for iPhone/Android

Tags: android, ios, object, image-recognition

I am working on a project both on Android and IOS.

Basicly, user will take photos of an object, place, logo, painting, etc. Store it in the app database. Then when the user takes the photo of the same object again the app will be able to match and confirm that these images are from the same or similiar source.

I checked a lot of APIs, I would rather free software but one time affordable payment will also work. Most of the APIs want to get paid per image count in database or per times the app tried to match images. Plus most of them work with a cloud server where the images are matched in a huge database.

I do not want these, I want a simple matching algorithm that can work offline on mobile devices.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). A lot of those services you mention are built on top of this or are similar. Since you only want offline mode this should work really well for you, although it will take more work on your end. You might want to start with the [object detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect.html#table-of-content-objdetect) tutorial, but there are tons of resources on OpenCV

Comment: Thanks, I've also checked this one, it seems like the most suitable one. I made this topic to see if I missed something, or there is good libraries that aren't popular out there.

Comment: Honestly this is the best option out there. I highly recommend it.

Comment: so about how much time do you think this task will take? learn+do